# Cannot compile c file from command line

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, cmd, codeblocks

I've just started using C and downloaded CodeBlocks gcc compiler. Now everything has been working fine, i.e. I could create simple source code and compile the `.c` file from either the command line or through CodeBlocks until just recently.

I had a simple program called `fairwell.c`, compiled to `fairwell.exe` via the command line by typing

```
gcc fairwell.c -o fairwell.exe
```

which displayed the following text:

```
Goodbye cruel world
```

I then deleted these `fairwell.c` and `.exe` files. Now everytime I try to compile a new `.c` file at the command line it keeps displaying this text `Goodbye cruel world` and does not compile the file. I can, however, still compile files directly through CodeBlocks.

Where is the problem?

Comment: what command are you using to compile the code ?

Comment: And on which operating system are you coding? How do you run your file? I would suggest compiling with `gcc -Wall -g fairwell.c -o fairwell.exe` and running with `./fairwell.exe`; use the debugger (e.g. `gdb`) to find bugs.

Comment: @hyde: Try `type -a gcc` or `which gcc`. The only `where` command I'm aware of is built into tcsh.

Comment: Yes that's what I did (thanks hyde), I changed the name of the farewell file to gcc. Its working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now everytime I try to compile a new .c file at the command line it
>   keeps displaying this text Goodbye cruel world and does not compile
>   the file.

Well, that means that when you run *gcc*, you actually run your old *farewell* program. So, you must have renamed it to *gcc* somehow, and it is in `PATH` before real *gcc*, or most likely in the current directory. If it works under your IDE, it means you should still have the original *gcc* too, so you shouldn't need to reinstall, at least.

Assuming you are operating under *cmd.exe* as indicated by the tag, then in the prompt where building fails, give this command:

```
where gcc
```

It should print a full path to whatever is run by that command. So examine that file (like, run it with the full path) to verify it is indeed your *farewell* program, then (just in case) rename it. Building should now work also from command prompt as well as from the IDE, and you can delete the renamed file.

PS. if you are actually using *bash* instead of *cmd.exe*, then try `which gcc` instead to find the wrong *gcc*.

Comment: Yea all I had done was rename the file as gcc somehow don't know how I did that. All working now. Thanks for the help

Comment: @MichaelSmith You should "accept" this answer when you resolved your problem with the help of this answer by clicking the white check mark.

Comment: @MichaelSmith No problem, and I personally happen to like this kind of "crazy" problems which seem like WTF until reason is discovered. Btw, the usual way to say "thank you" at SO is to upvote any answers and question you find useful.

Comment: Tried to upvote your answer there but apparently I need a better reputation (".) Just like in real life

Comment: @MichaelSmith Interesting, I thought you could always upvote answers to your own questions, same as you can comment on them always. But no matter, I meant that mostly as general suggestion to a new user :-)